# Mimicking a notification UIVIew with darkened background

Tags: ios, design-patterns

I am interested in creating a pop-up notification view similar to the design patterns seen below, where a `UIView` pops up and the rest of the screen is darkened, and done  without using a new modal view. Since this design pattern is so commonly seen, I was wondering if there is a "tried-and-true" way to doing it (or there a widely used open source framework like AFNetworking for downloading/uploading files and images)?

Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good start:

PopupView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PopupView : NSObject

+ (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view;
+ (void)show;
+ (void)hide;

@end
```

PopupView.m:

```
#import "PopupView.h"

@implementation PopupView

+(UIView *)sharedView {
    static UIView *_view = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken = 0;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
        _view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        _view.alpha = 0.6;

        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hide)];
        [_view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
    });
    return _view;
}

+ (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view {
    UIView *v = [PopupView sharedView];
    [v addSubview:view];
}

+ (void)show {
    UIView *v = [PopupView sharedView];

    v.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);

    id<UIApplicationDelegate> appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [[appDelegate window] addSubview:v];
}

+ (void)hide {
    UIView *v = [PopupView sharedView];
    [v removeFromSuperview];
    [v.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
}
```

Usage:

```
UILabel *l = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 21)];
l.text = @"Hello";
l.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[PopupView addSubview:l];
[PopupView show];
```

Or course instead of a label you can put any view(s) you want.